# I have troble converting some C code to Delphi

Tags: c, delphi

I need to convert some C code to Delphi and I got stuck at this, please help. Can I replace:

```
u_char chm_ac_codelens[] = {
            0, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0x77,
    };
```

with

```
const  chm_ac_codelens =[0, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 4, 0, 1, 2, $77];
```

Here is a piece of code I need help with:

```
u_char chm_ac_codelens[] = {
        0, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0x77,
};

u_char *
MakeQuantHeader(u_char *p, u_char *qt, int tableNo)
{
        *p++ = 0xff;
        *p++ = 0xdb;            /* DQT */
        *p++ = 0;               /* length msb */
        *p++ = 67;              /* length lsb */
        *p++ = tableNo;
        memcpy(p, qt, 64);
        return (p + 64);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the usage of `chm_ac_codelens`. Is it used in `MakeQuantHeader` as `*p` or `*qt`?

Comment: @zmechanic this is not the whole code, there are more arrays (longer ones) and more functions, but if I understand how to change this one, the rest would be easier. chm_ac_codelens is used as *qt but in other functions similar with MakeQuantHeader. The whole code is at the end of this https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2435#section-4.2

Comment: You could find the answer, at least for how to declare constant arrays in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A literal translation would look like this:

```
var
  chm_ac_codelens: array[0..15] of Byte = ( 0, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 4, 0, 1, 2, $77 );

function MakeQuantHeader(p: PByte; qt: PByte; tableNo: Integer): PByte;
begin
  p^ := $ff; Inc(p);
  p^ := $db; Inc(p); { DQT }
  p^ := 0; Inc(p);   { length msb }
  p^ := 67; Inc(p);  { length lsb }
  p^ := tableNo; Inc(p);
  Move(qt^, p^, 64);
  Inc(p, 64);
  Result := p;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Remy, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

No, I think you can't. You've defined a set not an array. The below should work for you:

```
program ideone;
    Const
        chm_ac_codelens : array[1..16] of Longint = (0, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 4, 0, 1, 2, 119);
begin
    Writeln(SizeOf(chm_ac_codelens))
end.
```

I've not been working with Delphi for 17 years, but this is as close as I can get to expected behaviour. Size of array in bytes is 64, as expected by your C code.

You can see my attempt here: http://ideone.com/p0KQrl

Comment: What about the function MakeQuantHeader? My guess is that it should looks something like `function MakeQuantHeader(var p: TIdBytes; qt: TIdBytes; tableNo: integer): TIdBytes;` and `*p++ = 0xff;` should be something like `p^ = $ff; Inc(p);`

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the whole code and knowing your Delphi skills and understanding of C. Essentially, `*p++ = 0xff;` is just a way to set array element value and move pointer to the next element. Without knowing where pointer `*p` is at the moment `MakeQuantHeader` is invoked it will be wrong to advice anything. If we assume that `*p` is at the beginning of an array you can safely set `p[0] = $ff;` then `p[1] = $db`, and instead of copying memory just keep setting values by hand or write a for loop. But you need to make sure that type of elements in the array is 4 byte integer.

Comment: `*p` is not at the beginning when `MakeQuantHeader` is called. Here is the hole code (at the end, Apendix B): https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2435#appendix-B . I already implemented the RTSP and RTP in Delphi, but I have problem with the C code, I didn't use it for so long...

Comment: Then your approach of using `p^ = $ff; Inc(p);` looks OK to me. It looks like an equivalent of `*p++ = 0xff;` C code.

Answer (score 0):

You're having trouble with MakeQuantHeader because it's the sort of abomination that C encourages.

It is using pointer arithmetic (one of the bug-attracting "features" of C) and mixing up characters with bytes.

Your first fix is to replace that u_char * with an array of bytes.

Your second fix is to deal with the index into the array instead of changing the "address" of the object to include the current offset.

Third is to verify that there really is enough space instead of risking stomping on memory.

Comment: If you don't know C well then it's best not to cast judgement. What is unsigned char if not the type used to represent a byte? Better to answer the question than to rant about that which you don't really understood.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan unsigned chars and bytes used to be one in the same.  Then came Unicode.

Comment: Nope. unsigned char is a byte, even with Unicode. wchar_t is for UTF16. I'm leaving aside weird systems with 16 bit chars.